# How to iterate through data frame?

Tags: python, python-cryptography

I'm searching on the encrypted cloud database, and the returned records are decrypted on the client side, I received the returned data on a data frame.
when the returned data is only one record, it decrypts the returned encrypted data. But when the returned data is more records, it raised the exception error as shown in code below
returned data is only one record

```py
    def search_by_SCKHAblindindex_age_sex_maritalstatus(db, Keywordage, 
    Keywordsex,Keywordmaritalstatus, SCKHAindexKey, enckey, uname):
  
    SCKHAindexsex = getSCKHABlindIndexC1(SCKHAindexKey,Keywordsex)
    SCKHAindexage = getSCKHABlindIndexC1(SCKHAindexKey, Keywordage)
    SCKHAindexmaritalstatus = getSCKHABlindIndexC1(SCKHAindexKey, Keywordmaritalstatus)
    cursor = db.cursor(dictionary=True)
   
    query = "SELECT sex_iv, sex_enc, sex_tag FROM Adult WHERE   sex_idx like'%{}%' AND age_idx like '%{}%' AND maritalstatus_idx like '%{}%';".format(SCKHAindexsex, SCKHAindexage,SCKHAindexmaritalstatus)

    print("Query is : ",query)
    cursor.execute(query)
    output = cursor.fetchall()
    print("Affect Rows are", output)
    rowcount=cursor.rowcount
    print("Number of Rows are", rowcount)
    df = pd.read_sql_query(query, con = db)
    sex_iv  =  df.loc[0:, 'sex_iv'].to_string().split(' ')[4]
    sex_enc = df.loc[0:, 'sex_enc'].to_string().split(' ')[4]
    sex_tag = df.loc[0:, 'sex_tag'].to_string().split(' ')[4]
    print("enckey",enckey)
    r=0
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
     try:
        plaintext = decrypt(enckey, uname.encode('UTF-8'), b64decode(sex_iv.encode('UTF-8')), b64decode(sex_enc.encode('UTF-8')), b64decode(sex_tag.encode('UTF-8')))
        r=r+1
        # print("plaintext: " + plaintext)
     except:
        return "An error has occurredd"
    return "Encrypted: " + sex_enc + ", Decrypted: " + plaintext.decode('UTF-8')
```

An example of the data is:

```
[
    {'sex_iv': 'F+W0/R0SywASqee0', 'sex_enc': 'WMsTfNc=', 'sex_tag': 'h6xW87yLmk+irzVwDsTlcg=='},
    {'sex_iv': 'Md5npLEcSdDFlq9J', 'sex_enc': 'yNGNcmg=', 'sex_tag': 'B0aqju14wBOuwQpuboOjqw=='},
    {'sex_iv': 'NqKMbfqgCFS+TkwQ', 'sex_enc': 'wcVyCQ8=', 'sex_tag': 'dODuWc5sDmGWPueQvqLNEA=='},
    {'sex_iv': 'gDdfuZIBttomJ6Sr', 'sex_enc': '0xRKHZo=', 'sex_tag': 'b9cIBycHciWKUkcYjOLpug=='}
]
```

The implementation of `decode()` looks like:

```py
def decrypt(key, associated_data, iv, ciphertext, tag):
    decryptor = Cipher(algorithms.AES(key), modes.GCM(iv, tag),).decryptor() 
    decryptor.authenticate_additional_data(associated_data)
    return decryptor.update(ciphertext) + decryptor.finalize()
```

Comment: Are the individual entries independently base64 encoded, or is the entire row base64 encoded? Can you provide an example set of rows, maybe 4 or 5?

Comment: the returned records are 4 records as shown  [{'sex_iv': 'F+W0/R0SywASqee0', 'sex_enc': 'WMsTfNc=', 'sex_tag': 'h6xW87yLmk+irzVwDsTlcg=='}, {'sex_iv': 'Md5npLEcSdDFlq9J', 'sex_enc': 'yNGNcmg=', 'sex_tag': 'B0aqju14wBOuwQpuboOjqw=='}, {'sex_iv': 'NqKMbfqgCFS+TkwQ', 'sex_enc': 'wcVyCQ8=', 'sex_tag': 'dODuWc5sDmGWPueQvqLNEA=='}, {'sex_iv': 'gDdfuZIBttomJ6Sr', 'sex_enc': '0xRKHZo=', 'sex_tag': 'b9cIBycHciWKUkcYjOLpug=='}]Number of Rows are 4
totaltime is:     0.2978484630584717
An error has occurredd

Comment: we based on sex_tag and sex_iv to decrypt sex_enc

Comment: What is the implementation for `decrypt()` is that a library or a custom method?

Comment: @JONSG def decrypt(key, associated_data, iv, ciphertext, tag):
    
    decryptor = Cipher(
        algorithms.AES(key),
        modes.GCM(iv, tag),
    ).decryptor()
    decryptor.authenticate_additional_data(associated_data)

     return decryptor.update(ciphertext) + decryptor.finalize()

Comment: It works well when only one record is retrieved, and decrypt the data correct, but the problem when retrieving many rows

Comment: @JonSG when I traced the exception it gives Row 0: Error decrypting: Invalid base64-encoded string: number of data characters (17) cannot be 1 more than a multiple of 4
Row 1: Error decrypting: Invalid base64-encoded string: number of data characters (17) cannot be 1 more than a multiple of 4
Row 2: Error decrypting: Invalid base64-encoded string: number of data characters (17) cannot be 1 more than a multiple of 4
Row 3: Error decrypting: Invalid base64-encoded string: number of data characters (17) cannot be 1 more than a multiple of 4

Comment: Are the rows you see the error on the same as what you have posted above?

Comment: @JonSG Yes, they are the same rows Affect Rows are                                       
Affect Rows are [{'sex_iv': 'F+W0/R0SywASqee0', 'sex_enc': 'WMsTfNc=', 'sex_tag': 'h6xW87yLmk+irzVwDsTlcg=='}, {'sex_iv': 'Md5npLEcSdDFlq9J', 'sex_enc': 'yNGNcmg=', 'sex_tag': 'B0aqju14wBOuwQpuboOjqw=='}, {'sex_iv': 'NqKMbfqgCFS+TkwQ', 'sex_enc': 'wcVyCQ8=', 'sex_tag': 'dODuWc5sDmGWPueQvqLNEA=='}, {'sex_iv': 'gDdfuZIBttomJ6Sr', 'sex_enc': '0xRKHZo=', 'sex_tag': 'b9cIBycHciWKUkcYjOLpug=='}]

Comment: Odd as none of those strings are 17 characters long and all decode fine for me.

Comment: So, what is the problem for me?

Comment: Is the function in the post works fine withyou? search_by_SCKHAblindindex_age_sex_maritalstatus()

Comment: I can't test it as I don't know (nor want to know) your keys :-P